# Ctl-Del Like in Vim

Tags: vim, editing

I really like the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> key in Vim insert mode, but I also need something like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd> in normal editing. Any idea if this exist, or how to implement it?

Also, how about a similar thing for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>?! I mean something exactly like <kbd>Del</kbd> key, but as easy as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dW` in normal mode is the closest to CTRL+Del behaviour.

If you *really* want something like Delete in Insert mode, why not just make a mapping for it?

```
:inoremap <C-J> <C-O>x
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I wanted. I made the following mapping though: ":inoremap <C-M> <C-O>dw". This way I have C-M to delete one word like CTRL-Del, and as I am using Dvorak, it is just beside C-W, which makes it very comfortable. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the expected behavior of ctrl-del is, but might `dE` be closer?

Answer (score 0):

`<c-o>dw` will mess in "`stuf<cursor>f secondword`" and in "`stuff<cursor> secondword`".

I use `<space><esc>ce` which works well.

Comment: I don't see it messing, it is fine with me. How is it messing on your side?

Comment: It transforms the first string into `"stuf<cursor>secondword"` and the second to `"stuff<cursor>secondword"` instead of `"stuf<cursor> secondword"` and `"stuff<cursor>"`. May be we are not looking for the same behaviour.